# Keras loss value not changing

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to apply a deep learning network on the Loan status dataset to check if I can get a better result than conventional machine learning algorithms.

Accuracy seems to be very low (even lower than using normal logistic regression). How can I improve it?

Things I've tried:
- Changing the learning rate
- increasing number of layers
- increase/decreasing number of nodes**

```
X = df_dummies.drop('Loan_Status', axis=1).values
y = df_dummies['Loan_Status'].values
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(50, input_dim = 17, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.00001)

model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=`['accuracy'])`

model.fit(X, y, epochs = 50, shuffle=True, verbose=2)
model.summary()
```

> Epoch 1/50
>        - 1s - loss: 4.9835 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 2/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9830 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 3/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9821 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 4/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9815 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 5/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9807 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 6/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9800 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 7/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9713 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 8/50
>        - 0s - loss: 8.5354 - acc: 0.4397
>       Epoch 9/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.8322 - acc: 0.6743
>       Epoch 10/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 11/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 12/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 13/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 14/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 15/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 16/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 17/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 18/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 19/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 20/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 21/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 22/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 23/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 24/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 25/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 26/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 27/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 28/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 29/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 30/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 31/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 32/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 33/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 34/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 35/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 36/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 37/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 38/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 39/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 40/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 41/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 42/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 43/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 44/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 45/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 46/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 47/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 48/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 49/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>       Epoch 50/50
>        - 0s - loss: 4.9852 - acc: 0.6873
>
> ```
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
> =================================================================
> dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 50)                900       
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 100)               5100      
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 100)               10100     
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 100)               10100     
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 100)               10100     
> _________________________________________________________________
> dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 101       
> =================================================================
> Total params: 36,401
> Trainable params: 36,401
> Non-trainable params: 0
> _________________________________________________________________
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to get a slight improvement by making the network deeper & adding dropouts, but I still think this can be improved further as using normal logistic regression gives a much better accuracy (80%+).

Does anyone know a way to achieve further improvement?**

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim = 17, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.0001)

model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])



model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 20, shuffle=True, verbose=2, batch_size=30)



Epoch 1/20
 - 2s - loss: 4.8965 - acc: 0.6807
Epoch 2/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6824 - acc: 0.7063
Epoch 3/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6091 - acc: 0.7040
Epoch 4/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.5642 - acc: 0.7040
Epoch 5/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6937 - acc: 0.7040
Epoch 6/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6830 - acc: 0.7063
Epoch 7/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6824 - acc: 0.7063
Epoch 8/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6824 - acc: 0.7063
Epoch 9/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6824 - acc: 0.7063
Epoch 10/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6452 - acc: 0.7086
Epoch 11/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6824 - acc: 0.7063
Epoch 12/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6824 - acc: 0.7063
Epoch 13/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.7200 - acc: 0.7040
Epoch 14/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6608 - acc: 0.7063
Epoch 15/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6940 - acc: 0.7040
Epoch 16/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.7136 - acc: 0.7040
Epoch 17/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6056 - acc: 0.7063
Epoch 18/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.5640 - acc: 0.7016
Epoch 19/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.7009 - acc: 0.7040
Epoch 20/20
 - 1s - loss: 4.6892 - acc: 0.7040
```